# Read data of a table(image) cell by cell using opencv

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am writing a mobile app to plot a graphical representation(graphs/charts) of table data. the user is taking an image of a statistical table. I have to detect the table and crop all the cells in an order to perform OCR using tessaract engine. 
Is there a proper way to recognize a table in an image and loop through the cells and save those to an array?

Up to now i have been able to clean the image as follows using opencv C++.

Code:

```
const char* filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : "test.jpg";

Mat src = imread(filename);
if(src.empty())
{
    //help();
    cout << "can not open " << filename << endl;
    return -1;
}

Mat dst, cdst, img2;

GaussianBlur(src,dst,Size(5,5),0);
cvtColor(dst, dst, CV_RGB2GRAY);
adaptiveThreshold(dst, dst, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,CV_THRESH_BINARY, 31, 15);
namedWindow("dst",WINDOW_NORMAL);

imshow("dst", dst);
```

Is there a way to loop through the cells and crop them in an order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, easy approach to find cells here:

You find contours in filtered image and build a bounding boxes round them.

Also you can use size and/or color information of specific contour to get rid of too small or too big ones.

Here's some code:

```
    Mat src = imread("g.png");

    cvtColor(src, src, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    Canny( src, src, 100, 200, 3 );
    imshow("g",src);

    findContours( src, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( src.size(), CV_8UC3 );
    char text[200] = "";
    CvFont font = cvFont(2,2);

    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
    drawContours( drawing, contours, i, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
    cv::Rect brect = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);
    if (brect.area() < 1000)
        continue;
    sprintf(text,"S = %d", brect.area());
    putText(drawing, text, cvPoint(brect.x+20, brect.y+20), 1, 1, CV_RGB(0,255,0));
    rectangle(drawing, brect, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 3);
    }


    imshow( "Contours", drawing);
```

[image]

Analyzing content and text recognition is quite a complicated task, and as i know no default methods in OpenCV to perform this, so it needs some research obviously.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. i will try this asap. i'm doing the ocr module using the tesseract engine. so need to crop each and every cell in and order to pass it to tesseract. is there anyway i can crop the contours in an order?

Comment: @user3411228 You should use some kind of sorting, like sorting by Y-axis first, and then by X-axis, also taking into consideration 'floating' borders of cells. Example here: http://codepad.org/GBJBG5Iv

Comment: thanks again.
I tried your 1st answer. Do you know the reason for the following error ?
'error C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.'

Comment: @ChathuraSam You are probably using MS Visual Studio. At first it is not error it's warning, so you probably have `'treat warnings as errors'` option in properties. By this warning they recommend to use their function instead of `sprintf`, but most users would not recommend to use it.

Comment: @chathuraSam hey there, I am also doing POC what you mentioned here, can you please share your findings or your program? help highly appreciated. Thanks!